# How can i sync my code live between a MacBook and a Windows computer?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, jetbrains-ide

They are connected to the same network, and I use Synergy to use them together. I use JetBrains IDE's and Visual Studio.

What I am looking for is that code synchronizes live between the two devices while I'm editing. So when I take my MacBook with me and do a bit of coding on it, when it reconnects to my home network, it should synchronize these changes with my computer. I want it do synchronize live at home. So without re-opening the file.

Is there a way to accomplish this with Git(hub)? (I don't know much about git) Anything that is fast enough for live sync on the home network is good enough.

Comment: What you describe is dropbox (or one of its alternatives), not git.

Comment: How would i go about setting this up?

Comment: Just create your repo in dropbox, box, google drive or one drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@[Sergio Tulentsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125816/sergio-tulentsev) is probably right, what you are trying to do is not what git is meant for. However, if you "really" want to do this, here is a hack that will get to close to your "promised land"  but not exactly there.

**To synchronize the code across both PC**

Consider using this extension [Run Pre/Post Save commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oneofone.save-runner) on VS code. I am sorry, I don't have an example script handy.

However, similar to what you will do for the **Run Pre/Post command extension**, here are some directions:
**This will only help keep the repo updated on Save.**

1. In VS code, install the "Run On Save" extension (choose the one by **emeraldwalker**, it seem there are quite a few others available.).
2. Go to File > Preferences > Settings > Workspace Settings. Scroll down and select **Code Action on Save**.
3. In the Displayed `settings.json` file, paste this json. Edit the commands to fit your case. For example, `"match": "\\.js"` Reference the extension page here [Run on Save Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave#overview)

```
{
  "emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "match": ".*",
        "cmd": "echo 'I am saved.' && cd ${workspaceRoot} && git add . 
         && git commit -m "auto commit on save" && git push"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

3. Save the file. Using the menu bar, go to View > Output. This is where the log information is displayed for the actions performed by the ruun on Save.
4. Test it out by editing and saving a file. (I need not mention that file should be in a git repo else it will throw an error).

Hopefully, that helps